# Adding an image to Facebook using social framework

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, afnetworking

I am getting this error when trying to upload the selected photo for the SLComposeViewController:

[CFNumber retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa1c2c00

The project builds without an errors or warnings.
Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)test:(id)sender {
    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

        API* api = [API sharedInstance];
        NSURL* imageURL = [api urlForImageWithId:IdPhoto isThumb:NO];        
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        [controller setInitialText:@"First post from my iPhone app"];
        [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.appcoda.com"]];
        [controller addImage:img];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
    }
}
```

any ideas why? thanks

**edit**:
Here is the viewDidLoad:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    API* api = [API sharedInstance];
    //load the caption of the selected photo
    [api commandWithParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"stream", @"command", IdPhoto,@"IdPhoto",label.text,@"weddingID", nil] onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
        //show the text in the label
        NSArray* list = [json objectForKey:@"result"];
        NSDictionary* photo = [list objectAtIndex:0];
        lblTitle.text = [photo objectForKey:@"title"];
    }];
    //load the big size photo
    NSURL* imageURL = [api urlForImageWithId:IdPhoto isThumb:NO];
    [photoView setImageWithURL: imageURL];
           NSLog(@"image url :%@",imageURL);

}
```

Comment: yeah ARC is being used

Comment: Are you getting the error in the debugger?

Comment: first check your imageURL is getting correct or not,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check your `imageURL` is getting correct or not,
There is no problem in SLComposeViewController with ARC.

or you can try if your photoView is imageview

```
- (IBAction)test:(id)sender {
    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

        [controller setInitialText:@"First post from my iPhone app"];
        [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.appcoda.com"]];
        [controller addImage: photoView.image];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: print it in `NSLog(@"image url :%@",imageURL)`

Comment: The NSLog shows that the imageURL is getting the correct path, but only in the viewDidLoad (see edit to original post). When the IBAction test is initiated, the debugger shows the same error without showing the NSLog.

Comment: than what you do with `photoView`??what is photoview , is it imageview?
either why you r not using direct `photoView.image`

Comment: WOW!! I am seriously grateful for your help. I totally had a brain fart ..yes my photoView is my image view. Thanks SO much!